# PHP Javascript websystem on android lollipop communicating with android wearable?

Tags: javascript, php, android, android-5.0-lollipop, wear-os

I've created a websystem on a 2008 R2 server running apache.

The system is used on `Android 5.0 lollipop` smartphones, I'd like to know if it's somehow possible to connect to the google play services API to allow me to connect to android wearables?

The end result ideally (and probably optimistically) is to load the webpage and have a button on an android watch which can communicate with the webpage (running on google chrome) on the android phone.

Is this in someway doable? - I'd like to keep it as some kind of webpage if possible.

All advice appreciated :)
Thanks !